# i am getting an error while making navigation drawer at "R.drawable.ic_launcher".How ton resove it??wher could i find R.drawable.ic_launcher?

Tags: android

my code is.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  
                mDrawerLayout,        
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
                R.string.drawer_open,  
                R.string.drawer_close 
        ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find ic_launcher image under

res->drawable->

so just check it if you have the image with this name or not

Comment: Hello @Lakhan, unfortunately I had to reject some of your latest edit suggestions because they did not work well for the image links. To inline an image, put a "!" in front of the link.